# Where can I find written decisions of the Employment Tribunal in England and Wales?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-research

Are Employment Tribunal decisions required to be published and where can I find written decisions of the Employment Tribunal in England and Wales?

Answer (score 4):

"[Written judgments are always issued](https://www.judiciary.uk/courts-and-tribunals/tribunals/employment-tribunal/employment-tribunal-england-wales/after-the-hearing/) and "[t]he Employment Tribunals are required by law to maintain a register of all judgments and written reasons."

Decisions of the Employment Tribunal are published [here](https://www.gov.uk/employment-tribunal-decisions) from 2017 onwards.

Even preliminary hearing judgments are published. E.g.:

- [*Mr J Casamitjana Costa v The League Against Cruel Sports*, 3331129/2018](https://www.gov.uk/employment-tribunal-decisions/mr-j-casamitjana-costa-v-the-league-against-cruel-sports-3331129-2018)